# Eclipse doesn't see file even it was in the package

Tags: java, eclipse

I have worked on a project in Java Spring and using Eclipse, I met this weird thing 2 days ago, everything run ok and it suddenly corrupted.

In Project Explorer the "java" and "resources" folders exist, but in Package Explorer, they don't show. Eclipse knew that "java" and "resources" as package, but it didn't see the file below, and it caused a thousand of errors because of this. Almost of errors were "Some class cannot be resolved".
See the images below:

[image: Project Explorer]

[image: Package Explorer]

I have tried many ways: clean, rebuild, re-import, restart eclipse, switch workspace, re-checkout the project in another place, download another eclipse but it is still the same.
Does anyone know how to solve this thing?

Comment: Can you post again the screenshots with expanding all folders/packages to see their contents?

Comment: The project's type should be **maven project**. Maven has the sources under src/main/java, src/main/resources and a normal ant based eclipse project under src. So the package root gets mangled. Try to open/import the project as maven project. And make a backup. Maybe I am wrong

Comment: Yes, it is maven project, the problem was from java version and I have solved it, thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But this is completly normal. You got those dirs included as "sources" and "resources" in Package Explorer - both are threated as "sources" so they are included in Eclipse's build path. This is completly normal - in Package Explorer dirs already included as sources are ommited from file tree. Your problem must be something else. Project clean should help indeed. Try to maven clean as well.

[image: "Missing" dirs are not missing at all]

Comment: Yes, you're right, the java and resources folder in package explorer were not exist in the file below is normal. The problem is from the version of java, with Java 1.8, I try clean project again and it normal now.
Thank your very much for your help.